# range() with a 'forbidden' value?

Tags: python, function, for-loop, range

Let's have an example. I have an ordinary function like this:

```
def function(x):
    for b in range(0, 5):
        print(b)
```

I want to have x as an exception in the range; this way, it would do something like this:

```
def function(x):
    for b in range(0, x):
        print(b)
    for b in range(x+1, 5):
        print(b)
```

But if what I want to do is longer than a simple `print()`, it will extend my function a lot. Is there any solution for doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Skip `x` inside the loop:

```
for b in range(0, 5):
    if b == x:
        continue  # skip to next iteration
    print(b)
```

Comment: @user3685355 If this answered your question/solved your problem don't forget to accept the answer by clicking the checkmark next to the answer. That's SO's "thank you" mechanism :)

Answer (score 3):

The two sub-ranges could be ["`chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain)ed" together:

```
from itertools import chain

def function(x):
    for b in chain(range(0, x), range(x+1, 5)):
        print(b)
```

Or you could also use a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions):

```
def function(x):
    for b in (v for v in range(0, 5) if v != x):
        print(b)
```

The latter can easily be generalized to support the exclusion of multiple values:

```
def function(*x):
    for b in (v for v in range(0, 5) if v not in set(x)):
        print(b)

function(3)     # -> 0 1 2 4
function(1, 3)  # -> 0 2 4
```